# Setting up a Github action to remove changes to particular files from any Pull Requests

Tags: git, github

I've created a github project that is intended to be forked by different organisations and deployed by them individually.

Each fork will likeley change and commit its own config file, in this case mkdocs.yml

When these forks contribute back upstream I want their PR's to automatically exclude any PR changes to mkdocs.yml (and other specified files).

Seems a Github action might work best for this to remove the file after they initiate the Pull Request.

Does this seem the right approach? How could I achieve this?

Comment: One downside of removing it might be that you'd have to add a commit or rewrite someone else's branch to undo the change. Perhaps instead you could use a status check that fails if a PR has changes to a specific file, and then the person can fix it themselves. You may even want the check to look at every commit in the PR to make sure none of them modifies the file, to prevent the case where someone modifies the config and then undoes it in another commit. The end state wouldn't modify the file, but after the merge the history of the file would change- not sure if if that matters to you also.